# Objective-C character encoding - Change char to int, and back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Simple task: **I need to convert two characters to two numbers, add them together and change that back to an character.**
What I have got: (works perfect in Java - where encoding is handled for you, I guess):

```
int myChar1 = (int)([myText1 characterAtIndex:i]);
int myChar2 = (int)([myText2 characterAtIndex:keyCurrent]);
int newChar = (myChar1 + myChar2);
//NSLog(@"Int's %d, %d, %d", textChar, keyChar, newChar);
char newC = ((char) newChar);

NSString *tmp1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", newC];
NSString *tmp2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", newString];
newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", tmp2, tmp1]; //Adding these char's in a string
```

The algorithm is perfect, but now I can't figure out how to implement encoding properties. I would like to do everything in UTF-8 but have no idea how to get a `char`'s UTF-8 value, for instance. And if I've got it, how to change that value back to an `char`.
The `NSLog` in the code outputs the correct values. But when I try to do the opposite with the algorithm (I.e. `-` the values) then it goes wrong. It gets the wrong character value for weird/odd characters.

Comment: One thing, you can't just add and subtract UTF-8 characters, as they can be as many as 6 bytes long. Also, internally NSStrings use a UCS-2 like code point for their characters and you are getting back a 2-byte UniChar, not an int or a char.

Comment: `H + H` would land you at code point `U+90`, which is not a character. Is this really what you want?

Comment: @deceze Well, I simply want to add them together and store the new value in an char (to make it displayable) then later subtract it again. - basic encryption

Comment: @Nideo Maybe you should look into binary XORing them or existing forms of encryption instead? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSString works with unichar characters that are 2 bytes long (16 bits). Char is one byte long so you can only store code point from `U+0000` to `U+00FF` (i.e. Basic Latin and Latin-1 Supplement).

You should do you math on unichar values then use `+[NSString stringWithCharacters:length:]` to create the string representation.

But there is still an issue with that solution. You code may generate code points between `U+D800` and `U+DFFF` that aren't valid Unicode characters. The standard reserves them to encode code points from `U+10000` to `U+10FFFF` in UTF-16 by pairs of 16-bit code units. In such a case, your string would be ill-formed and could neither be displayed nor converted in UTF8.

Also, the temporary variable tmp2 is useless and you should not create a new newString as you concatenate the string but rather use a `NSMutableString`.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your strings are NSStrings consisting of numerals which represent a number.  If that is the case, you could try the following:

Include the following headers:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Then use the following code:

```
// convert NSString to UTF8 string
const char * utf8String1 = [myText1 UTF8String];
const char * utf8String2 = [myText2 UTF8String];

// convert UTF8 string into long integers
long num1 = strtol(utf8String1, NULL 0);
long num2 = strtol(utf8String2, NULL 0);

// perform calculations
long calc = num1 - num2;

// convert calculated value back into NSString
NSString * calcText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%li" calc];

// convert calculated value back into UTF8 string
char calcUTF8[64];
snprintf(calcUTF8, 64, "%li", calc);

// log results
NSLog(@"calcText: %@", calcText);
NSLog(@"calcUTF8: %s", calcUTF8);
```

Comment: They are not numbers. They are any user inputted text. But this seems like it may work either way?

Comment: If they are not numbers, then strtol() will return 0, however the conversion between NSString and const char * should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you meant, but from what I understood, you wanted to create a NSString with the UTF-8 string encoding from a char?

If that's what you want, maybe you can use the `initWithCString:encoding:` method in NSString.